# Create new page in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system

Iam new in drupal. I want to create a page and want to add data in page directly with out using backend content. I have created a page like this, page-test.tpl.php. How can I call this newly created page in browser?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create your own custom module.Let the module name be test.Create 2 files namely test.info and test.module.Declare a `hook_menu` function inside the test.module file.Since your module name is test your `hook_menu` will be named as `test_menu`.
`Hook_menu` enables modules to register paths in order to define how URL requests are handled. Paths may be registered for URL handling only, or they can register a link to be placed in a menu.

Test.module

```
function test_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['test'] = array(
    'title' => 'My Page',
    'description' => 'Study Hard',
    'page callback' => 'test_simple', //Calls the function
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}   

function test_simple() {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  return array('#markup' => '<p>' . t('My Simple page') . '</p>');
}
```

Test.info

```
name = Test
description = Provides a sample page.
core = 7.x
```

After adding this try clearing the `drupal cache` and then navigate to `/test`.Try this [link](http://cryptosmith.com/node/373) if you are a beginner.Try reading `hook_theme` which allows you to use your custom template.More about `hook_theme` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).Hope it might help u mate.. :)

Comment: Based on your comments, I have created a folder named 'test' (with test.info and test.module file) and uploaded it to module folder in root directory. and, I tried to execute page like /?q=test. But it showing page not found error. :-(

Comment: Have u enabled the custom module in the modules list page..??and have you tried clearing the cache...??

Comment: Yes, I have enabled module and tried after clearing cache. :(

Comment: After enabling custom module, showing this code in every page also.. "function test_menu() { $items = array(); $items['test'] = array( 'title' => 'My Page', 'description' => 'Study Hard', 'page callback' => 'test_simple', //Calls the function 'access arguments' => array('access content'), ); return $items; } function test_simple() { return array('#markup' => '
' . t('My Simple page') . '

'); }"

Comment: have u opened the `<?php` tag at the start of your module..??

Answer (score 0):

Pages in drupal are stored in the database, not in actual code files like old websites used to. The template files (.tpl.php) are exactly that - templates. So for example, lets say you have blog content. You'd have to create a content type of 'Blog'. you could then create a template file (ex. node--blog.tpl.php) which would format the way the blog pages would look. But you would still need to add new pages through the drupal interface in order to add them to the site. You could always use an input type of PHP if you'd like to include php in the body of the page.

If you simply want to display a php file in your browser from your site, you can just upload a php file of your choice to your sites/default/files directory and access it directly via the file path.